# Regular Expression for flex to look ahead(string containing only one underscore)

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I am trying to find a way to achieve recognizing a token that has only one underscore and it is not allowded to start or finish with an underscore.Something like:

```
abc_def:VALID TOKEN
_abc:NOT VALID TOKEN
abc_:NOT VALID TOKEN
```

I cant understand how i can allow only one underscore when there are characters after the underscore that will be repeating.Is this possible with a regex in flex/lex?

Comment: write us possible input and expected output

Comment: You shall tell what characters are allowed in your tokens except one underscore. Now I see one answer that handles spaces and one that don't. What about numbers? Non-english letters? Can one line contain multiple tokens? What regexps have you already tried and why  are they not suitable for you?

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hI1rI0)

Regex: `^[^_]+_[^_]+$`

Explanation:

1. `[^_]+` -> whatever is not a `_` with at least one character.
2. `_` -> An underscore
3. The same as 1
4. `^` and `$` are anchors that delimites the start and the end of the string respectively.

If you want to restrict the regex to be 3 chars leng, use `{3}` instead of the plus.

Answer (score -1):

An example in Python:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.findall(r'\b[^\s_]+_[^\s_]+\b', 'abc_def, abc__def, __abc_def, abc_def__')
Out[2]: ['abc_def']
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure lex/flex don't support word boundaries (`\b`), but this answer is wrong even in Python.  It assumes the first and last character of the desired match are word characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`).  The OP hasn't said what the other characters are, just that they can't be underscores.

Comment: @AlanMoore As you said, the OP hasn't specified what the other characters may be. So my solution MAY BE wrong, but you cannot be sure unless the OP says so. I have no idea about the word boundary support, though. Don't know flex.